# MySQL in a message board - retrieving messages and all relevant info

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to web development (HTML, PHP, MySQL, etc.) and thought it might be good idea to develop a pretty simple message board as an excercise.

I've set up a database for storing everything I need. The tables are as follows:

- ### subjects

  - id (Int(4), PK)
  - title (VARCHAR(50))
  - creatorID (Int(4))
  - creationTime (datetime)
- ### messages

  - id (Int(6), PK)
  - subjectID (Int(4))
  - authorID (Int(4), FK)
  - postTime (datetime)
- ### users

  - id (Int(6), PK)
  - username (Varchar(10))
  - password (Char(32))
  - email (Varchar(50))
  - signupdate (datetime)

This is just a rudimentary structure; the data types for the fields are potentially far from optimal.

I'm now at the point where I'm trying to display all the messages in a given subject. I'm doing this by letting my showthread.php catch the subject ID via `$_GET['subjectID']`.
I obviously need to fetch all relevant info from the db, that is, the `username` of the author, the `postTime` etc.
At first I approached this in the following way:

1.) Get all messages with the subjectID (One query)
2.) For every message, get user info
3.) Get the post count of the user via `COUNT(*)`

Then I thought maybe I could do all this in one single query - In hindsight I should have defined a post count column in the `users` table, but for the sake of training I continued without that column.  So I went ahead and created the following two queries:

1)

```
SELECT message, postTime, username, signupdate, postcount FROM messages as m
INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.authorID = u.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS postcount, u.id FROM messages AS m INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.authorID = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
) AS c ON c.id = m.authorID WHERE m.subjectID = $subjectID ORDER BY m.ID ASC
```

2)

```
SELECT message, postTime, (
SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.id = om.authorID
) AS username, (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages As im WHERE im.authorID = om.authorID
) AS posts
FROM messages As om WHERE subjectID = $subjectID ORDER BY om.id ASC;
```

As already mentioned, they both do the job for now. 
I think that the first version will perform pretty poorly once my db grows sufficiently large, because the inner subquery always queries the post count for ALL users, no matter if they even posted in the subject in question. 
So I guess my question is this: Would query number 2) be a reasonable approach for a db of non-negligible size? If not, what different kinds of queries could I use? I feel a little overwhelmed by the sheer amount of angles from which you can tackle a problem with SQL and I'm afraid I might be missing something. 
Maybe performance isn't even an issue with any of the aforementioned queries since the MySQL implementations nowadays are sufficiently smart? :-)

I appreciate any input on the subject. Please keeep in mind that I'm trying to solve this without introducing an additional post count field in my `users` table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are worried about performance, when your query lasts for minutes, its a good idea to create a view or a materialized view.

A view is a table built with a query. This means you can create a view retrieving all necessary data for the problem you mention (bring all user activity (posts, messages, etc) and have it in 1 table. This way when you retrieve the data you save the time of joining tables.

More info in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Materialized views instead are regular tables that fulfill the same job of the view with the difference you need to run a cronjob with some frequency to update the info.

The uses or both depend of how often different types of CRUD operations are performed. Also you can use indexes to speed retrieval of data, however in tables with a lot of insertions or deletions is not a good idea because these operations slow down.